# Diff on each subset of a data frame column

Tags: r, subset, diff

I have a data frame with ID, year, and month. I need to group by year and month and get the unique IDs from that group. I want to compare the unique IDs to the prior year, month group, how many IDs were added and how many were subtracted.

Kind of shooting in the dark but I tried the following, doesn't work:

```
connections <- df %>%
  group_by(year, month) %>%
  arrange(year, month) %>%
  diff_data(unique(as.vector(~ID)), lag(unique(as.vector(~ID))))
```

Sample Data

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A1", "A2","A4", "A1", "A4", "A5"),
year= c(2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2012), 
month= c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3))
```

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3S15d.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First would do `aggregate` on both month and year. In this approach would list all IDs added and deleted each month, and get `length` to count how many added and deleted each month.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  aggregate(ID ~ year + month, ., unique, drop = FALSE) %>%
  group_by(month) %>%
  arrange(year) %>%
  mutate(addedID = mapply(setdiff, ID, lag(ID), SIMPLIFY = FALSE),
         num_addedID = lapply(addedID, length),
         deletedID = mapply(setdiff, lag(ID), ID, SIMPLIFY = FALSE),
         num_deletedID = lapply(deletedID, function(x) length(na.omit(x)))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(month, year) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

**Output**

```
  year month ID addedID num_addedID deletedID num_deletedID
1 2010     1 A1      A1           1        NA             0
2 2011     1 A1                   0                       0
3 2012     1 A1                   0                       0
4 2010     2 A3      A3           1        NA             0
5 2011     2 A2      A2           1        A3             1
6 2012     2 A4      A4           1        A2             1
7 2010     3 A3      A3           1        NA             0
8 2011     3 A4      A4           1        A3             1
9 2012     3 A5      A5           1        A4             1
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c("A1", "A3", "A3", "A1", "A2","A4", "A1", "A4", "A5"),
                 year= c(2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2012), 
                 month= c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: Sorry seems my sample data set could have been a bit more thorough. I took out; group_by(month), and added the month to arrange; arrange(year,month). Seems to be working the way I want now. Thanks!